# How to make DRF serializer compatible with uppercase

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My Boss decided to migrate *Rest API* from *ava to *Django*. 
The previous Java-guy designed every database field in camelCase, such as `userName`, and every API POST data in camelCase.

When I refactor these to *DRF*, I got following Model. The REST API also receive post data in camelCase, so I must lower the post data or `is_valid()` will return `False`.

```
class Useraccount(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(db_column='userName')
```

REST API request data:

```
{
"userName": "Jenny"  # I need lower "userName" to "username"
}
```

Is there a method to let *DRF* compitable with uppercase POST DATA? I don't want to lower these `userName` in every `APIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i don't think there is any easy way to accomplish this. What you can do however is to have a write serializer which will do this for you.

```
class WriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userName = serializers.CharField(source='username', write_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ['userName']

class ReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ['username']
```

I'm not sure but you can also do it in one model by manually specifying all the fields and telling which field is write_only and which is ready_only, but that also is a lot of work I assume.